# Batch file if statement weirdness with variable assignment and expansion

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file and I'm trying to work with some variables in an `if` statement. For example I `set` a variable either from command line parameter 1, or if there is no parameter 1 then I have a default value. Then, depending on whether the value is the default or an argument from the command line I perform some other function.

**What I notice is that the variable I've assigned in the if statement isn't available after the `if` statement is over. Can someone explain why that is?**

For example this will fail to echo what's in TEST1:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

if .%1==. (
    set TEST1=NOTFOUND
    echo %TEST1%
) else (
    set TEST1=%1
    echo %TEST1%
)
```

If I run that batch file with or without an argument it returns `ECHO is off.`. It thinks the variable is still empty.

If I attempt to get the variable after the `if` statement, it works:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

if .%1==. (
    set TEST1=NOTFOUND
) else (
    set TEST1=%1
)
echo %TEST1%
```

I'm sure this has to do with variable expansion but it really threw me. It looks like I will assign another variable in the `if` statement like `set USING_DEFAULT_TEST1=TRUE` and `set USING_DEFAULT_TEST1=FALSE` or compare to the default value or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.